# C Program hangs on EOF check

Tags: c, eof

I'm working in a Linux terminal and have I'm writing a program that requires the user to hit CTRL-D at the end of their input to signify the end of input. The program hangs on the while loop waiting for another input to scan even though I'm pressing the CTRL-D button. The weirdest part is that if I press it enough times, it will register and store the EOF keystroke to my variable, and finish the program correctly.

My code snippet:

```
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);
while(index<size && c!=EOF){
    A[index] = c;
    index++;
    scanf("%c",&c);
}
```

I stepped through my program in gdb and every time I've entered my input and it has scanned it all, it waits for more input, at which point I use the CTRL-D keystroke, but it doesn't even register it. I haven't found anything in researching this issue, and I'm confused as to why it works sometimes (if I press it enough times), and not others. What is going on?

Comment: That worked! Any ideas as to why my other notation didn't work reliably? What do you think was going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf`, unlike `fgetc`, never sets it parameters to `EOF`. In case `scanf` is unable to read its parameter(s) due to eof, it simply leaves them unchanged. So the check `c!=EOF` is obsolete.  You may check for `feof(stdin)`. Alternatively, you may check the return code of `scanf`:

```
int rc = scanf("%c", &c);
```

It returns the number of parameters it succesfully reads, or sometimes it returns EOF.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to implement the desired behavior using `fgetc()`

```
char c = fgetc(stdin);
while(index<size && c!=EOF){
  A[index] = c;
  index++;
  fgetc(stdin);
}
```

From the man page of fgetc: "fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error." I guess scanf fails to properly recognize EOF. (see below)

Alternatively, use the `feof` function provided by stdio.h:

```
while(index < size){
  c = fgetc(stdin);
  if(feof(stdin)) break;
}
```

It's generally recommended to use the `fgets()` family of functions for I/O-Operations, since they are (mostly) safer than `scanf`.

Man pages with further information: fgetc, feof, scanf.

EDIT: After posting my answer and reading the comments under the question: scanf() *returns* EOF (like fgetc) when encountering an end of file error. This means checking the return value of scanf will fix the problem, e.g.

```
while(index < size && scanf("%c", &c) != EOF){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: scanf can't return EOF.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`. Using `!feof(stdin)` in this way is a classic error. There is no "EOF character" in Linux.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns a char cast to an int, at least if the documentation is correct. Why is using `feof()` here wrong?